# Angular $http fires everytime I go out of a page then back in

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http, caching

I have an Ionic app that is making an $http request to the server. I am listing a number of articles and the user has the option to go into a single article. My problem is that I noticed that when I go into the page that lists the articles it makes a call to retrieve that list of articles. if I go out of that page then back in again it makes that call again. Is there a way to cache that data so that it only makes a call to the server if, in the instance of "pull to refresh" or set a timer for it to make calls?

My service:

```
.factory('Articles', function ($http) {
    var articles = [];
storageKey = "articles";

    function _getCache() {
        var cache = localStorage.getItem(storageKey );
        if (cache)
            articles = angular.fromJson(cache);
    }
    return {
        all: function () {
            return $http.get("http://jsonp.afeld.me/?url=http://examplesite.com/page.html?format=json").then(function (response) {
                articles = response.data.items;
                console.log(response.data.items);
                return articles;
            });
        },
        get: function (articleId) {
            if (!articles.length) 
            _getCache();
            for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
                if (articles[i].id === parseInt(articleId)) {
                    return articles[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

and here is my controller:

```
.controller('ArticleCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, Articles) {
    $scope.articles = [];
    Articles.all().then(function(data){
        $scope.articles = data;
        window.localStorage.setItem("articles", JSON.stringify(data));
    }, 

    function(err) {
       if(window.localStorage.getItem("articles") !== undefined) {
          $scope.articles = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("articles"));
        }
    }

    );
})
```

Comment: Do you want to call backend when click a button?

Comment: no just navigating between views. Like if I have an about page and article page switching to about then back to article causes angular to make another server request.

Comment: You can cache with $http.get('/url',{cache:true}); Then you have to find how you can manipulate this cache. I remember something like $cache factory and stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already caching the data, so just change your `all` to this:

```
all: function () {
    var cache = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
    // If cache, return a promise wich resolves with the cache
    if (cache) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(angular.fromJson(cache));
        return deferred.promise;
    } else {
        // if no cache, do a http call to get the data
        return $http.get("http://jsonp.afeld.me/?url=http://examplesite.com/page.html?format=json").then(function (response) {
            articles = response.data.items;
            // store in cache
            localStorage.setItem(storageKey, articles);
            console.log(response.data.items);
        });
},
```

Comment: There is also a build in cache that you can use directly with $http setting "cache:true" in your call configuration.

Comment: Yeah but he needs the localstorage cache else where in his code as you can see, so caching it in localstorage makes it available on other places

Comment: sorry missing "}". I am getting the error $q is not defined? I added it to my function then got the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined

Comment: Ok fixed it by adding $q to my factory function. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @devqon just a quick question. Does this allow for the page to add additional articles as they are updated on the server?

Comment: Not yet, if they are updated a lot I would't cache the results, otherwise you can use a timestamp and reload if the time is for example 2 hours later than the timestamp. Or you can create a refresh button that does a new call to fetch the data

Comment: ok great thanx. I am working with Ionic so without the caching it takes a moment to load articles which doesn't feel too native. still struggling with getting the user experience right in this matter. I recon I am just going to implement "pull to refresh". Thanks again for all the help!